# How do I fix an error caused in using IPython.Display.Audio (OSError [Errno22] Invalid argument:...)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, syntax-error, runtime-error

I'm currently trying to write a simple Python (3.6.6) program that can grab a Youtube video, play it back, and graph the waveplot and spectogram of the file. But it only runs properly in Jupyter notebook. I'm using [this site](https://towardsdatascience.com/music-genre-classification-with-python-c714d032f0d8) as a guide on the program. I want to make sure it can run in IDLE as well, but so far no luck. Here's the code section regarding the file retrieval / path set and trying to play it back:

```
# Downloading audio
audiostream = video.getbestaudio()
# audiostream.download()


from tkinter import filedialog as fd

# Asking where to save it
print("Select the directory...")
dir_name = fd.askdirectory()
print(dir_name)
path = dir_name + "/" + video.title + ".wav"
print(path)
audiofile = audiostream.download(filepath=path)

import IPython.display as ipd

# Playing back the audio
print("Playing back audio...")
ipd.Audio(filename=path)
```

And the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\(myPCname)\Desktop\YTpyDwnlder.py", line 45, in <module>
    ipd.Audio(filename=path)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\IPython\lib\display.py", line 110, in __init__
    super(Audio, self).__init__(data=data, url=url, filename=filename)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\display.py", line 627, in __init__
    self.reload()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\IPython\lib\display.py", line 121, in reload
    super(Audio, self).reload()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\display.py", line 652, in reload
    with open(self.filename, self._read_flags) as f:
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:/Users/(myPCname)/Desktop/gui/Low Roar - "I\'ll Keep Coming".wav'
```

The path seems correct for the most part so I'm not sure why the program thinks it's wrong. I've tried to double and triple check through looking up other sites on Python string formatting for files and I can't find what's wrong. I've also tried inserting '\' to all potential single or double quotes within (provided they don't already have the '\' before them) the string but it still doesn't like it (I know this is a futile attempt and is redundant).

How can I fix this?

Also sorry if the tags are incorrect; this is my first time posting a question on here.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I found that the problem was due to invalid characters in the filename ('"' is changed to '#' in the filename).